# how to upload a pdf file and other string parameter in rest wcf service

Tags: c#, pdf, upload, http-post, wcf-rest

I had created a rest wcf service and now i want to post the pdf file and some other string data to it so what is the Correct way to do it

1) converting the pdf to base64 string and then form the xml and post it to rest web service decode it in the rest service.

2) directly uploading using the below code

```
     byte[] pdfFile = File.ReadAllBytes("pdf file path here");WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://test.site.fr/Testfile");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = pdfFile.Length;
    request.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(pdfFile, 0, pdfFile.Length);
    stream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    reader.Close();
```

which is better with respect to large files and if any other compression required

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use multipart/form-data. C# does not have an inbuilt multipart/form-data parser so use this parser written by one of the developers from the C# community.

[HttP Multipart Data Parser](https://github.com/Vodurden/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser)